# Generate YYYYMM for each month quarter and between two dates

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I want to generate Yearmonth (YYYYMM) for each quarters between two years and associate a rank number for each line.

| Date_Begin | Date_End |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 2023 |

I retrieve a yearmonthrank as below:

```
SELECT  GENERATE_ARRAY(1,((Date_End-Date_Begin )*4)) as period_rank
...
UNNEST(period_rank) AS period_yearmonthrank
```

Which returns:

| period_rank |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| ... |
| 12 |

Now, I have no idea how I could generate this output for yearmonth part?

| period_rank | yearmonth |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 202103 |
| 2 | 202106 |
| 3 | 202109 |
| 4 | 202112 |
| 5 | 202203 |
| 6 | 202206 |
| 7 | 202209 |
| 8 | 202212 |
| 9 | 202303 |
| 10 | 202306 |
| 11 | 202309 |
| 12 | 202312 |

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY y, q) AS period_rank,
       FORMAT('%d%02d', y, q) AS yearmonth, 
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(2021, 2023)) y, UNNEST([3, 6, 9, 12]) q
;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: awesome ! Thank you Jaytiger,
Can you detail me this '%d%02d' please ? You recover data from the 2 part of unnest with the last one on two digits ?

Comment: Yes, First `%d` will format year number and second `%02d` will format a quarter month with 0 added if month is a single digit.

Comment: Simply you can change them like this :  `FORMAT('%d%s', y, q)`  and `UNNEST(['03', '06', '09', '12'])`  will make same result.

Comment: Thank you for those precisions, regards !